# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Runner Name'

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

Every time i run my program it keeps popping up with - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Runner Name'.   'Runner name' is a field name within my database. And  the line with `da.Fill(dt)` gets highlighted. Can someone please help. I'm desperate

```
Public Class AddNewRace
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        ' open connection '
        cnn.Open()
    End If 
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID as [ID]," & _
                                        "Runner Name as [Name], Running Average Speed, Cyclying Average Speed, Swimming style, Calories Burned FROM Training log ORDER BY ID", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    'fill datatable'
    da.Fill(dt)

    Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt
    ' close connection'

    cnn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    ' add data to table '
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        ' open connection '
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then


        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Members (ID, Runner Name, Running Average Spee d, Cyclying Average Speed, Swimming style , Calories Burned) VALUES ('" & Me.txtID.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtRunnerName.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtRunSpeed.Text & "' , '" & Me.txtCycleSpeed.Text & "', '" & Me.txtSwimStyle.Text & "', '" & Me.txtCaloriesBurned.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Training log SET ID=" & Me.txtID.Text & ", Runner Name='" & Me.txtRunnerName.Text & "', Running Average Speed='" & txtRunSpeed.Text & "', Cyclyin Average Speed='" & txtCycleSpeed.Text & "', Swimming style='" & txtSwimStyle.Text & "', Calories Burned='" & txtCaloriesBurned.Text & "' WHERE ID='" & txtRunnerName.Tag & "' "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    ' Refresh Data in list'
    RefreshData()

    Me.btnEdit.PerformClick()

    ' close connection'

    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably find the syntax `select runner name` is being treated as the shorthand form of `select runner as name` which would make the following `as` rather problematic. Even if they're not being interpreted that way, standard SQL will treat `Runner` and `Name` as two distinct tokens unless you tell it otherwise.

If you have spaces in your column names, you already *know* how to fix that (square brackets to delimit it), you may not just realise it:

```
select [Runner Name] as [Name]
```

You may also have to do that to the other columns containing spaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space in the name of your column, you need to wrap it in brackets.

`Runner Name` should be `[Runner Name]`

Of course, many of your columns have spaces, you'll need to adjust them all this way.  This will be true for your insert, update, and delete statements as well.

You might consider refraining from using spaces in your column names, and designing your DB columns with camel case, such as `RunnerName`

Comment: This isn't *fully qualifying* the name (that would involve adding a dot) -- it's *quoting* the name.